# Download the dependencies source code used at android studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio

Now,google use android studio,i can add dependencies at build.gradle as follows:

dependencies {
    compile 'mobi.parchment:parchment:1.6.9@aar'
}

but sometime i want to see the source code "mobi.parchment:parchment@aar",maybe i want to modify it or use to eclipse but not use the gradle plugin

Answer (score 1):

If AndroidStudio didn't download the source code, you can force the download of source (and javadoc) of your AAR dependency by adding these lines in the build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'mobi.parchment:parchment:1.6.9@aar'
    compile 'mobi.parchment:parchment:1.6.9:sources@jar'
    compile 'mobi.parchment:parchment:1.6.9:javadoc@jar'
}
```

Then on AndroidStudio in the Projet tab, expand the external Librarie and right clic on your lib (`parchment1.6.9`), click "Library Properties ..." and the "+" button. the source's jar file is in the gradle cache under `${user_Home}/.gradle/modules-2/files-2.1` directory; you can select it.

(Once is done you don't need anymore to declare the source dependencies; so your build.gradle can contain only :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'mobi.parchment:parchment:1.6.9'
}
```

I know it's an ugly process, but it's the only workaround I found until now.